# Guidance for applying Advantage/Disadvantage to attack rolls vs. contests and saves vs. checks

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage

If a PC is attacking with advantage, does that mean that they also have advantage when making a special attack that does not use an attack roll, like shoving or grappling?

If a PC has disadvantage on their Dex saves, does that mean that they also have disadvantage on Dex-based checks/contests?

For example, a creature hit by a giant spider's Web ability becomes restrained.  Their movement drops to zero, they have disadvantage on their attacks, and opponents have advantage when attacking them.  They also have disadvantage when rolling Dex saves.

RAW would dictate that they can still make Acrobatics checks without penalty, even though they are stuck in a web and have a hindered ability to dodge.  RAW would also seem to indicate that shoving a bound PC is just as difficult as shoving a free PC.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### This a DM Ruling Case

The rule doesn't specify that an Ability Check or Contest has Disadvantage when a creature is Restrained. (Appendix A; Conditions)

> • A restrained creature’s speed becomes 0, and it can’t benefit from
>   any bonus to its speed.
>    • Attack rolls against the creature have advantage, and the creature’s attack rolls have disadvantage.
>    • The creature has disadvantage on Dexterity saving throws.

Granting Advantage/Disadvantage in such a case is a DM option, and that is pointed out in the rules.  This is a case where rulings by the DM are called out as integral to the game (Advantage; Basic Rules p. 57; PHB p. 173).

> You usually gain advantage or disadvantage through the use of special abilities, actions, or spells. Inspiration can also give a character advantage (as explained in chapter 4, “Personality and Background”).  **The DM can also decide that circumstances influence a roll in one direction or the other and grant advantage or impose disadvantage as a result**.

If it makes sense to the DM that this circumstance, being stuck in the web, grants Disadvantage to an Acrobatics check then the DM will rule that Disadvantage applies to that circumstance.  The DMG supports this approach. (DMG p. 239).

> Advantage and disadvantage are among the most useful tools in your DM's toolbox. They reflect temporary circumstances that might affect the chances of a character succeeding or failing at a task.

FWIW:

> RAW would also seem to indicate that shoving a bound pc is just as difficult as shoving a free pc.

The web that restrains him is easily seen as having enough of a grip on the character that it prevents him from falling down or moving suddenly, as with a shove.

Answer (score -1):

**Rules As Written**

> If a PC is attacking with advantage should they also have advantage
>   when taking a special attack action that does not use an attack roll
>   like shoving or grappling?

Advantage on attack rolls means just that. If you are rolling a D20 to see if an attack hits, it is an attack roll.  Grappling and shoving, RAW, are different kinds of actions.

> If a PC has disadvantage on their Dex saves should they also have
>   disadvantage on Dex based checks/contests?

Saving throws are not checks or contents. So, RAW, no. To illustrate the point, having proficiency on a saving throw doesn't grant proficiency on all checks with that stat.

**DM ruling**

Obviously, a DM is given the ability to make calls based on the situation and a DM can house rule that whatever granted the advantage also affects other types of rolls.

Personally, I'd argue it is easy to shove or grab a character who tangled up in spiderwebs. The important part of ruling like this, is that it has to be decided the same way for all PCs and NPCs the same.

Comment: Proficiency isn't circumstantial.  I wouldn't think to apply it in the way I'm describing.